# Wattage needed for heater to heat up a filament dryer

Tags: heat

I am going to DIY a filament dry box.

I am going to use a 50L container and a 30W/24V kapton heater. Using the formula Q = mCp(Tf - Ti), with m = 64.65g (50L of air, from https://www.aqua-calc.com/calculate/volume-to-weight), Cp = 1 g/j/K (from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Table_of_specific_heat_capacities), Tf = 40C (for PLA) and Ti = 8C at room temperature, I get 64.65 * 1 * 32 = 2069. Then using t = Q / P, with P. = 30 W, I get 68.69 s. which means the 30 W heater will heat up the entire 50L container in a little bit more than 1 minutes.

I feel that this calculation is horribly wrong because I tested the heater on a 22L container it couldn't even heat that one up in 1 minutes. I am very new to physics and please point out my mistake and provide a correct solution.

Comment: Your calculations seem to be ok but you’re not taking account of conduction - the air has a mass of a few grams but will quickly conduct heat into the enclosure, so unless it’s very well insulated it will take much longer to reach the target temperature.  You’ll also need to factor in the mass of the filament (3D print filament I assume), and the latent gear of vaporisation if the water that you’re wanting to expel

Comment: Yes, I just want to validate the theoretical calculation. But I didn't expect other factors will have such a huge impact on the system. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Your calculations seem to be correct in principal.

But, you are missing a few points!

**(1)** Your System consists of a mass to be heated, a energy input and a energy output.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fxl1oz.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

**(2)** The rise in system Tempratur `ΔTs(t)` is determined by `∫(Ei-Eo)dt/(ms*cs)`.

In words: The integral over the delta between your energy influx and outflux `∫(Ei-Eo)dt` defines the net energy absorbed by your system in a given timespan. The tempratur rise is detremined by the specific heat capacity and mass `ms*cs` of your system.

Please see: [Specific heat capacity, Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Specific_heat_capacity) and [Heatflux, Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heat_flux)

**(3)** Your energy influx consists, for the sake of this application, soley of your heater elements power. The power of `30W nom` can be assumed to be around `25W net` as some power is lost in cables outside of the system, other effects and tolerances may also apply.

**(4)** You energy outflux consists of multiple factors on the other hand.

- Thermal `conduction` between your system and the environment
- Thermal `convection` between your system and the environment
- Thermal `radiation` between your system and the environment

Are the most prominent.

Please see [Conduction, Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermal_conduction) , [Convection, Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convection) and [Radiation, Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermal_radiation)

**(5)** Your max system temperatur is reached, when a equilibrium is reached: `tn:Ei-Eo(t)=0 -> T(tn) = Tmax` . This will happen - assumming constant and temperatur invariant `Ei` - as `Eo` is generally temperatur variant. So `∫(Ei-Eo)dt` becomes `∫(Ei-Eo[T(t)])dt` which makes analytical approaches rather inconvinient.

You can solve this issue, by using approximated values from books.
Please see: [Heat transfer coefficient, Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heat_transfer_coefficient)

**(6)** To approximate the time required to heat the system, you can also use these simplifications.

- `Specify` required tempratur rise
- `Determine` your system mass
- `Approximate` the energy outflux
- `Compute` net energy influx

And `et voilà` you get: `t=(ΔTs*ms*cs)/En` with `En=Ei-Eo` beeing your net energy influx with the units `J/s`

**NOTE:** This is a strong simplification, as a linear system is assumed and approximate values are used to determine the net energy influx.

**(7)** If you have a fixed maximum time boundary, you can apply tolerances to several factors. This way, you can make sure you can keep and maintain your target accross the systems lifespan.

- Apply a derating to your heater power. Assume e.g. 15W
- Overestimate your system mass with a factor of e.g. *2
- Overestimate your system energy outflux by a factor of eg *1.5

`If you are still able to maintain your timing requirements whilst using these deratings, you are good to go.`

**(8)** You can use simulation tools for these kind of problems.

Freeware can be found, but generally i recommend MatLab/Simulink. Please see [MatLab/Simulink Thermal Models](https://www.mathworks.com/help/simscape/thermal-models.html)

Comment: Thank you for your detailed explanation, I didn't expect these factors can have such a great impact and there are much more to be considered in real life than the ideal scenario. My question might sound silly because I have no engineering background. It always amazes me that so many things I thought would work actually turned up to be so much more complicated when I started to do some maker stuffs. Anyway, thank you again for your help.

Comment: @J.C.Stark I did not interprete your question as silly - on the contrary rather. I gave such a detailed answer, as you (in my opinion) showed - by means of your formulations - the knowledge and intrest to not only read it, but also understand it!